# Anaconda Environment in prompt/PS1 in MacOS?

Tags: bash, anaconda, command-prompt, prompt, ps1

When I was in Ubuntu installing Anaconda and activating a virtual environment modified my prompt to look like that:

> (current-env)user@machine:dir

or as you define in .bashrc.

Now that I installed Anaconda in MacOS my prompt remain the same. I tried to configure that from Anaconda doing:

> conda config --set changeps1 no

but nothing changed.

How can I modify my .bash_profile to have the current environment in PS1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to have that changing my shell from bash to zsh.

You can install zsh from [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions, Conda has provided automated configuration for a number of shells via the `conda init` command. This command will edit relevant `.*rc` files to enable such features of PS1 change.  Please see `conda init --help` for details.